# Mongoose Mongo DB using NodeJs Error : throw new TypeError('Undefined type at `' + path +

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The moment I add below 'content: `Binary Data` in the below code I get the following error. What am I missing

Code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MeterdataSchema = new Schema({
  serialno: String,
  info: String,
  active: Boolean,
  content: "Binary Data"
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Meterdata', MeterdataSchema);
```

Error

```
>> Waiting for server reload...
D:\Users\rohanindotech\Developer\yoangfull2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:
362
    throw new TypeError('Undefined type at `' + path +
          ^
TypeError: Undefined type at `content`
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
    at Function.Schema.interpretAsType (D:\Users\rohanindotech\Developer\yoangfu
ll2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:362:11)
    at Schema.path (D:\Users\rohanindotech\Developer\yoangfull2\node_modules\mon
goose\lib\schema.js:305:29)
    at Schema.add (D:\Users\rohanindotech\Developer\yoangfull2\node_modules\mong
oose\lib\schema.js:217:12)
    at new Schema (D:\Users\rohanindotech\Developer\yoangfull2\node_modules\mong
oose\lib\schema.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Users\rohanindotech\Developer\yoangfull2\server\ap
i\meterdata\meterdata.model.js:6:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
Done waiting!
```

Comment: Do you want the `content` field to be a fixed value?

Comment: yes always fixed. have to ensure its encoded as it has to be transmitted over json

Comment: Then you can use mongoose [`virtual`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#virtualtype_VirtualType-get) type.